# How can I insert a doc!{...} into a typed MongoDB collection?

Tags: database, mongodb, rust, traits, borrow-checker

I have a rocket web server and I want to add an auth-token to my sync-MongoDB database. However when I try to `insert_one` I get an error that the borrow trait of Token is not implemented for the Document type.

```rust
#[derive(Debug, Clone, Serialize, Deserialize)]
struct Token {
    username: String,
    token: String,
    timestamp: i64
}
```

```rust
fn set_token(&self, username: &String, token: &String) -> Result<InsertOneResult, mongodb::error::Error> {
    let result = self.tokencol.insert_one(doc! {username: username, token:token, timestamp: 0}, None);
    return result;
}
```

Here is the relevant snippet of my code. The type of `self.tokencol` is `Collection<Token>`.

I tried implementing the Borrow trait myself but did not have any success with that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use `Collection<Token>` as your collection type, you cannot use `doc!{}` with `.insert_one()` since the collection is expecting a `Token` and not a generic `Document` (even if it looks like a token). You can either:

- Just make a `Token`:

  ```rust
  self.tokencol.insert_one(
      Token {
          username: username.to_owned(),
          token: token.to_owned(),
          timestamp: 0,
      },
      None,
  )
  ```
- Convert your collection into an untyped version using `.clone_with_type()` to `Document`:

  ```rust
  self.tokencol.clone_with_type::<Document>().insert_one(
      doc! {
          username: username,
          token: token,
          timestamp: 0,
      },
      None,
  )
  ```